# How to merge all footer cells in a responsive, bootstrapped DataGrid?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, bootstrap-4, ascx

I have a multi-column DataGrid in an ASP.NET user control with a footer whose columns I'd like to merge as one cell.  How do I do that? I'm using C# for the code-behind, Bootstrap 4 beta classes to automatically hide columns as the viewport width changes, Font-Awesome for some symbols/icons, and below is the DataGrid inside my ASCX markup. Currently it all works, except that I want the footer row to be all merged as one cell. In the end, the items in my first column's FooterTemplate should spread out across the successfully merged footer cell because I've already prepared the styling for that (I'm presuming that all of the other empty footer cells will get merged into the first footer cell, and that the content of the first footer cell will be kept).

```
<div class="col-lg-12 ">  
    <div class="table-responsive"> 
        <asp:datagrid id="dgEggGradeDetails" UseAccessibleHeader="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" ShowHeader="True" ShowFooter="True" runat="server" DataKeyField="EggID" CellPadding="0" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True" OnSortCommand="dgEggGradeDetails_SortCommand" OnItemCreated="dgEggGradeDetails_ItemCreated">
            <FooterStyle CssClass="">
            </FooterStyle>
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Egg ID" SortExpression="EggID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEggID" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EggID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <div id="dvHidePickledOrDeviled" runat="server">
                            <div style="text-align: left; float: left; width: 80%; height: 100%;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblHideFooter" runat="server" CssClass="" Visible="True">Hide All Eggs (Deviled, Pickled)</asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <div style="text-align: right;">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnHidePickledOrDeviled" runat="server" OnClick="ShowOrHidePickledOrDeviled" CssClass="" Visible="True" CommandName="HidePickledOrDeviled">
                                    <i id="iHidePickledOrDeviled" class="fa fa-minus-square-o" style="font-size: 40px;" title="Hide Eggs with 'Deviled' and 'Pickled' grades"></i>
                                </asp:LinkButton>       
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="dvShowPickledOrDeviled" runat="server">       
                            <div style="text-align: left; float: left; width: 80%; height: 100%;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblShowFooter" runat="server" CssClass="" Visible="True">See All Eggs (Deviled, Pickled)</asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <div style="text-align: right;">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowPickledOrDeviled" runat="server" OnClick="ShowOrHidePickledOrDeviled" CssClass="" Visible="True" CommandName="ShowPickledOrDeviled">
                                    <i id="iShowPickledOrDeviled" class="fa fa-plus-square-o" style="font-size: 40px;" title="Show Eggs with 'Deviled' and 'Pickled' grades"></i>
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                            </div>                      
                        </div>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Egg Name" SortExpression="EggName" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-md visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-md visible-lg">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label  ID="lblEggName" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EggName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Egg Grade" SortExpression="EggGrade" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblGrade" Runat="server" />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblGradeErrorMsg" Runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>

                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Confirm Grade" SortExpression="Grade" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlConfirmGrade" Runat="server"></asp:dropdownlist>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblConfirmGrade" Runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>


                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Edible End Date" Visible="False" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label id="lblEdibleEndDate" Runat="server" text='<%# String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EdibleEndDate2"))%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Egg Grade Sync Date" Visible="False" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label id="lblEggGradeUpdatedDate" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EggGradeUpdatedDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>

                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Expiration" SortExpression="ExpirationStopDate" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label id="lblExpirationStopDate" Runat="server" text='<%# String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ExpirationStopDate"))%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>

                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Reason for Grade Change" SortExpression="GradeChangeDescription" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlGradeChangeReason" Runat="server"></asp:dropdownlist>                          
                        <asp:Label id="lblReasonErrorMsg" Font-Size="10px" Runat="server"></asp:Label><INPUT id=hiRegistrationID type=hidden value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RegistrationID") %>' name=hiRegistrationID Runat="server"></input>
                        <input id="hiCurrLetGrade" type="hidden" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Grade") %>' name=hiCurrLetGrade Runat="server">
                        <input id="hiCurrLetGradeID" type="hidden" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GradeID") %>' name=hiCurrLetGradeID Runat="server">
                        <input id="hiGradeEnteredDate" type="hidden" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GradeEnteredDate") %>' name="hiGradeEnteredDate" Runat="server" />
                        <input id="hiEggEmail" type="hidden" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Email") %>' name="hiEggEmail" Runat="server" />
                        <input id="hiQualityStatusID" type="hidden" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CurrentQualityStatusID") %>' name="hiQualityStatusID" Runat="server" />
                        <input id="hiEggLaidDate" type="hidden" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EggLaidDate") %>' name="hiEggLaidDate" Runat="server" />
                        <input id="hiStoreName" type="hidden" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StoreName") %>' name="hiStoreName" Runat="server" />
                        <input id="hiTypeAEgg" type="hidden" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TypeAEgg") %>' name="hiTypeAEgg" Runat="server" />
                        <input id="hiTypeBEgg" type="hidden" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsTypeBEgg") %>' name="hiTypeBEgg" Runat="server" />
                        <input id="hiEdibleTypeID" type="hidden" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EdibleTypeID") %>' name="hiEdibleTypeID" Runat="server" />
                        <input id="hiGradeChangeReasonID" type="hidden" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GradeChangeReasonID") %>' name=hiGradeChangeReasonID Runat="server">
                        <input id="hiGradeChangeDescription" type="hidden" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GradeChangeDescription") %>' name=hiGradeChangeDescription Runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID ="lblCurrLetGrade" EnableViewState ="True" Visible = "False" Runat = "server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Grade") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Label ID ="lblEggGrade" EnableViewState ="True" Visible = "False" Runat = "server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EggGrade") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>

                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>                        
            </Columns>
        </asp:datagrid>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code-behind, inside the ItemCreated event handler, place the following code to merge the entire footer row:

```
protected void dgEggGradeDetails_ItemCreated(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
    {
        int newcolspan = 1;
        int totalColumns = e.Item.Cells.Count - 1; 

        for (int i = totalColumns; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            if (e.Item.Cells[i].Visible)
            {
                e.Item.Cells.RemoveAt(i);
                newcolspan++;
            }
        }

        e.Item.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = newcolspan;
    }
}
```